# Need to group a series of numbers with no key value - Ruby, Python, Javascript

Tags: language-agnostic, etl

Here's my problem.  I have a large file with contains a payment record with associated invoice(s) that are associated to it.  The file is a flat file with positional based entries which I can handle but the ability to sequence this is baffling my tired brain.

I'm sure this is simple so be kind.

The file structure is simplistically shown here:

```
600060006600 payment details 
700010001000 invoice details
700010001001 invoice details
600060006680 payment details
700010001002 invoice details
600060006690 payment details
700010001004 invoice details
700010001005 invoice details
700010001006 invoice details
```

Sometimes a payment will have one invoice, sometimes more than one.  The 6 will always be the payment and 7 will always be the invoice.

Restricted to core libs in a script language (ruby, python or javascript) is required due to the tools set we're using otherwise I would have hammered this thing out by now.

Comment: Can you show how it would look grouped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no matter what language you choose, what you're trying to do looks like an ETL. The process of taking some records somewhere in some format, and putting them somewhere else in another format, possibly after some conversion.

Here's the gist of what you want to do:

1. Iterate through the file,
2. Take each text line, and parse it into a dictionary/object/record (in your examples, the first space you encounter is the sole delimiter)
3. Make additions/transformations to your record (eg. take the id, apply some logic on it to infer the type)
4. Possibly put it back in some other data store, whether file or DB or else.

As to how that can be done in X language, the implementation varies, and that seems out of scope for this question. I'll give examples using Ruby, but it's only because I'm comfortable with it, it could be done in many languages.

To get started, you might want to read up on the different CSV libraries in languages, they give some examples as to pretty much that sort of task. For instance, here's Ruby's [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). DBMS's like Postgres are also able to load CSV files. (pgfutter will even create your table definition and import your CSV if you're working with Postgresql)

As to what kind of tool to use, it depends on how many records to process you have and the complexity of the transformation. If you only have a few (say arbitrarily < 10k), making objects and iterating that will be fine and done in less than a few seconds. Whereas if you have a lot (say > 1M), you might want to do it in a DB query (unless you can't use a DB).

The DBMS will be generally more performant on large data sets and allows you to do stuff like joins rather easily, but a language like Ruby is more expressive if you have to do more complex transformations. (I wouldn't want to program an algorithm in SQL.)

If you need both? You can mix the two by using an ORM such as Activerecord or Squeel. (or whatever you're comfortable with, really) You can then use your language to do what it needs and interact with the database.

Choose the best tool for the job. And beware of premature optimization!

Comment: Absolutely right Jonathan, what I'm trying to do is create a payment record where the value starting at six is the object that contains the invoice records which start with 7.  I have to continue to iterate through all of the payment records in a file until I have properly grouped all of the payments to their invoices.  Does that make sense?  I think what I'm looking for is more along the lines of should I break these out into individual objects to be processed, do it in stream or maybe build a hash map with array values?  Thinking through plausible and effective solutions for the ETL job.

Comment: Depends on how many you have. If you only have a few (`< 10k`), making objects and iterating that will be fine, whereas if you have a lot, you might want to do it in a DB query (unless you can't use a DB). It will be generally more performant on large data sets, but I find the syntax harder to nail down for more complicated logic. Best tool for the job. And beware of premature optimization ;o)